# Looking for a file on the computer

Tags: c#

So here is what I have in there now. I am getting a whole lot of red lines in this and not sure why. I need to know how to take the code you all gave me below and put it in to a checkbox method so that it runs when you hit a button labeled next.

```
public Question()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Question_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void UnRe_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UnRe.Checked == true)
    {
        string rootDirectory = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()[0].RootDirectory.FullName;

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( rootDirectory,
                        "file.exe", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
}// closes class

private void Infection_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Support.Checked == true)
    {}
}

private void Other_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

IEnumerable<string> GetAllAuthorizedFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
{
    foreach (var fname in GetAuthorizedFiles(root, searchPattern))
        yield return fname;

    foreach (var dir in GetAuthorizedDirectories(root))
    {
        foreach (var fname in GetAllAuthorizedFiles(dir, searchPattern))
            yield return fname;
    }
}

string[] GetAuthorizedDirectories(string root)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetDirectories(root);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}

string[] GetAuthorizedFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(root, searchPattern);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What **is** the error?

Comment: SearchOption.AllDirectories will not work from the root directory of the C: drive, you'll always run into a directory that you don't have read access to.  The directory that contains restore points.  You'll have to do this the slow way, iterating directories yourself.  Literally slow btw, this can easily take several minutes on a terabyte drive.  Not the kind of code you'd ever enjoy running.

Comment: @HansPassant - you should turn the comment into an answer

Comment: I'll have to pass.  A solution won't ever make anybody happy when they discover how long it takes.  SO allows users to express their discontent, that's going to be a heavily downvoted answer.

Comment: @HansPassant, please reconsider.  Stalking your excellent answers by questions is hard enough without having to backtrack comments as well!

Comment: @HansPassant also the instructions for how to manually traverse the file system must exist 100s of times on the web, let alone on SO. Massive duplication wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I am not worryed about how long it takes to look for the file. Time is not an issue. The error that I am getting is this " Access to the path 'C:\Document A System.UnauthorizedAccessException was thrown: "Access to the path 'C\Documents and Settings' is denied."

Comment: Yes, reparse points are a problem as well.  You really, really can't use SearchOption.AllDirectories.  A good google query is "c# enumerate files recursively".

Comment: here are 2 msdn articles that will help you contruct(and handling the exceptions) what you need, 1) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx , 2) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx

Comment: next time post only usefull code... empty method give nothing and simply add code for nothing

Comment: Sorry just a copy from the program as is. Will make sure to do that next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time is not an issue as you say, you could iterate through all directories trying to get their files. Whenever you run into an [UnauthorizedAccessExcpetion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) you simply ignore that directory and move to the next one in line.

Here is the implemantation of a recursive file enumeration method, as suggested by Hans Passant:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllAuthorizedFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
{
    foreach (var fname in GetAuthorizedFiles(root, searchPattern))
        yield return fname;

    foreach (var dir in GetAuthorizedDirectories(root))
    {
        foreach (var fname in GetAllAuthorizedFiles(dir, searchPattern))
            yield return fname;
    }
}

string[] GetAuthorizedDirectories(string root)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetDirectories(root);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}

string[] GetAuthorizedFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(root, searchPattern);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
}
```

And here is how you would call it from your code:

```
string[] files = GetAllAuthorizedFiles(rootDirectory, "File.exe").ToArray();
```