# Quickest way to use C# to programmatically search entire computer for several dozen unique filenames?

Tags: c#, performance, .net

I am writing a program to do compatibility checking... Basically I am going to have a database that contains filenames, and version info for specific file.

This database will store hundreds of unique filenames, and these files could exist in many places on a clients computer.

I could probably do additional work and find out where each file is "suppose" to exist, but obviously that will sometimes be machine dependent, for example 32 bit system files might exist in program files, 64 bit could be either program files or program files (x86).

However, it is also possible that multiple versions of these files exist in different places on the computer, and could be stored in temp data directories like appdata.

So really what I would like to do is search the entire root drive, for all instances of these files, check the file version, and compare that against what is in the database.

Searching the entire root directory and all sub directories for 1 file is time consuming, let alone iterating through hundreds of unique filenames 1 at a time searching entire root.

Would it be easier to just return a list of all files on machine and location, write that to temp table, and then i can iterate through my list of files in sql which would be much quicker?

Dunno, but I would like this search to be fairly quick, not take 2 hours.... ;-)

Comment: My C drive alone has a 1/4 million files.  Not sure how you expect this to not be slow considering not only do you want to get the file names but you are also checking versions as well.  How many files are in your database that you want to compare with?

Comment: This may be helpful to you: [Looking for a file on the computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763859/looking-for-a-file-on-the-computer/17765088#17765088). Even though the accepted answer's algorithm is slow, it seems to be the only way to enumerate all files in a computer avoiding the [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx).

Comment: @Geek The number of files will vary depending on what the users is checking compatibility for. It could be as little as 12 files, and upwards of 100. Would it matter if they have indexing turned on, and can the windows indexing be accessed programatically?

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena That article basically states that if the UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown, it ignores that file/directory. I am not sure that would be acceptable. I would be more curious what causes that error, and if running my program as admin, would resolve that error if it is caused by a permissions error. Additionally, some of the directories are often "hidden" directories, like Appdata, ill probably have to account for that as well.

Comment: No - certain files you don't have access too - even as an Admin.  For example - Documents and Settings on Windows 7 or Windows 8.  See my answer for a fast way to do this.

Comment: @Geek Ok, it looks like Documents and Settings doesnt really exist anyways it is what is referred to as a junction point, and really those files are now found under "users", so sounds like I would still have access to files I need, but would also need to have that other code in place to catch the unauthorized exception error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this code against my C drive (SSD) with a few files.  It found 291,935  files in  14.79 seconds.  Now you just need to iterated over your collection of files and match by name - then check versions.  The use of the Parallel For / Foreach loop would prove useful here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = new BuildFileList();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var files = b.GetFiles();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} files in {1} seconds", files.Count, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class BuildFileList
    {
        public List<FileInfo> GetFiles()
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
            var directories = di.GetDirectories();
            var files = new List<FileInfo>();
            foreach (var directoryInfo in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                    GetFilesFromDirectory(directoryInfo.FullName, files);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            return files;
        }


        private void GetFilesFromDirectory(string directory, List<FileInfo> files)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            var fs = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            files.AddRange(fs);
            var directories = di.GetDirectories();
            foreach (var directoryInfo in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                    GetFilesFromDirectory(directoryInfo.FullName, files);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 15 seconds for 300,000 files is respectable. I am sure your SSD drive is helping a lot with that performance, which is why you mentioned it? would it be prudent to store the file list returned in an array or database, and then perform my search for "my" files on that array or database?

Comment: @JP: This code puts the files into a `List<FileInfo>`, which you can then search sequentially, or sort and then do a binary search.

Comment: Nice! Looks like an excellent start to what I am looking for, thank you gentleman!